# Cannot reopen an Analysis Services Tabular Project the second time– error database already exists in the detached state

Tags: ssas

Using SQL Server Analysis Services 2019 running in Tabular mode, I get this error every time I open an existing Tabular Project solution in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.3, though I don't think the version is the issue). Even creating a new Analysis Services Tabular Project, closing it, and opening a second time again causes the same error.

> An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database.
>   Reason: The operation cannot be executed since the database with the
>   name of 'Data Warehouse Tabular_5a21b9d1-2c2e-43e3-9174-981ccddf6f66',
>   ID of 'Data Warehouse Tabular_5a21b9d1-2c2e-43e3-9174-981ccddf6f66'
>   already exists in the detached state in folder '\?\C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\Data Warehouse
>   Tabular_5a21b9d1-2c2e-43e3-9174-981ccddf6f66.0.db'. Either attach the
>   database or delete the folder and retry the operation.

This error is described very well here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jason_howell/2013/07/22/cannot-reopen-an-analysis-services-tabular-project-the-second-time-error-database-already-exists-in-the-detached-state/

Unfortunately, implementing the suggested fix of making sure that my DataDir was referenced in my AllowedBrowsingFolders setting did not make a difference.  Here are my current settings:

[image]

Running `SystemGetSubdirs 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\'` in an MDX connection returns no results.  However, running SystemGetSubdirs on the parent OLAP folder does return three of the six folders in that directory (including the Data folder).  I have forced the Data folder to inherit the permissions of the OLAP folder, and forced those permissions on all child objects, and I have tried giving Full Control to the Data folder to the 'Everyone' user, to my user and to the SSAS service account user.  I have tried creating a new data folder on the root of my C: drive and holding the databases there, but none of this has made a difference.  I've restarted the SSAS service after these changes.

Comment: The fix outlined in the link worked like a charm. I'm sorry it didn't for you but thanks for posting it.